# CVS: How to list all files with a certain tag including their revision number?

Tags: cvs

Given:
-There is a certain module in CVS, let's call it test_module
-There is a certain tag which I have applied, let's call it test_tag

Now, how can I get a list of all the files within the module 'test_module' that have been tagged with 'test_tag', including their CVS revision number?

The output should be something like this:

```
/path/to/file1 1.2 
/path/to/file2 1.2.4.2 
/path/to/file3 1.3
```

etc.

I have an old CVS version (1.11 something) which I cannot change myself. It does not have the 'cvs ls' command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you do not have access to the CVS server.

You will have to check out workspace to this tag `cvs co -r test_tag test_module`.

Then you have to get the versions for each file. You have a choice of either

- Doing a `find` on all files, excluding those in `CVS` directories and running `cvs status` on each file, `grep`ing for the version. This is the much slower but uses only user-level commands.
- `find`ing all the `CVS/Entries` files and `cat`ing them, `grep`ing out the directory entries, and using `awk` to print just the filenames and versions. You'll need a small amount of trickiness to add the paths back to the files. This is probably your best bet. It is much faster, but you're getting into the CVS metadata files that you're not really supposed to look at as an end-user.